# Custom collection crashes DataGrid on Edit

Tags: wpf, collections, datagrid, toolkit, itemssource

Im currently trying to bind the DataGrid.ItemsSource to a custom RowCollection, which implements IList and INotifyCollectionChanged:

`Public Class RowCollection(of T)

    Implements IList(Of T)

    Implements INotifyCollectionChanged

Private _List As New List(Of T)

...`

(Sorry for the VB code, I'll be translating all my code to C# soon.)

Notice the class **does not** derive from any existing CLR collection. I created my own class because I need to override GetItemAt, in order to implement record paging.
The Collection Internally adds and removes objects from its own private List `_List`.

Now, I am able to view the items in a DataGrid, but as soon as I double click a cell to edit, I recieve an **InvalidOperationException: 'EditItems' is not available.**.

My question is, what other interfaces should I implement in order to make my collection fully compatible with DataGrid?

Comment: +1 I remember that I had the same problem but have not tried to dig into it because I had not the time. As far as I remember, I ended up in using ObservableCollection<T> as ItemsSource synching them with my own collections. I'm curious if someone has a solution.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do can be done in a simpler way.  Use an existing collection, and then put the DataGridView into virtual mode and implementing the CellValueNeeded(object, ...CellEventArgs) handler. Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode.aspx The purpose of virtual mode is to support the kind of paging scenario you have in mind.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention Im using the WPF DataGrid in the WPF Toolkit for .Net 3.5. The link you mentioned is about WinForms.

Comment: @HighCore - yes it is. Thanks for the clarification, I should have noticed that.

Comment: @HighCore: You have accepted the answer from Vincent Vancalbergh. Was it the IEditableCollectionView-interface that had to be implemented? Has it worked for you?

Comment: @HCL - Yes. Actually, I ended up using a normal ObservableCollection<T> and created a derived ListCollectionView, where I define custom logic for retrieving items and getting item count. Therefore I was able to create some sort of data virtualizatiion. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) you can read the following:

> Editing
>
> By default, you can edit items
>   directly in the DataGrid. To guarantee
>   that edits can be committed and
>   canceled correctly, the objects in the
>   DataGrid must implement the
>   IEditableObject interface.
>   Alternatively, you can set the
>   IsReadOnly property to true to disable
>   editing in the DataGrid.

The IEditableObject interface is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx)
Also see IEditableCollectionView [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditablecollectionview.aspx)